# Are there any fricatives pronounced behind the tonsils?

Tags: phonemes, consonants, allophones

I have noticed that I have the ability, like all, to force air out of the little places behind the tonsils, and I was curious if this is an actual articulation? I don't know what part of the mouth, or vocal tract, this would be.

I notice that the more I pronounce it, the more it kind of sounds like a pharyngeal fricative. I am not quite sure which part of the mouth exactly is the pharynx, I just know I can pronounce pharyngeal sounds. I guess either it is a pharyngeal fricative and I am not used to thinking of it differently, or perhaps an allophone of the pharyngeal fricative?

---

My mouth anatomy is a little "lacking," but I think the area I am speaking of is between the *vellum* and the *posterior faucial pillar.*

Answer (score 2):

Pharyngeal, epiglottal and glottal frictives are produced lower in the throat that the palatine tonsils, which is presumably what you're looking at. A uvular fricative would not be fully behind the tonsils, but would be *at* the tonsils.

Comment: My mouth anatomy is a little "lacking," but I think the area I am speaking of is between the _vellum_ and the _posterior faucial pillar._